# Can the "Integrity constraint violation: 1048" be due other functions on the same page?

Tags: php

I'm a newbie, getting experience working on a football club project. I'm trying to insert a new team in the Teams table and I get the "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'TeamName' cannot be null", error. I've made the column NULL and I've checked for execute duplication and both seem OK. I have several other functions on the same page, to get a specific fixture, update, delete a team, and also I have a Search function. All of that code would be just too big to show here but could it be the other functions that are interfering with INSERT? When I press "Get" a fixture, I get all the details of the fixture as expected but the search function also triggers and it shows all the data on the fixture table too. Should I be separating all these functions on different pages or just the search one? Here's the Insert code just in case you can pinpoint what is wrong. Thank you ever so much!

```
    if (isset($_POST["Insert"])) {
    insertTeam();
}

function insertTeam() {
    
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $GLOBALS['servername'] . ";dbname=e0912343_Fixtures", $GLOBALS['username'], $GLOBALS['password']);
        
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        
        $statement = $conn->prepare(" INSERT INTO Teams (TeamName, TeamLogo) VALUES (:TeamName, :TeamLogo)");
        
        $statement->bindValue(":TeamName", $_POST["TeamName"]);
        $statement->bindValue(":TeamLogo", $_POST["TeamLogo"]);
  
        $result = $statement->execute();
        
        print_r($statement->errorInfo());
        
        if ($result) {
            $GLOBALS['message'] = "A new Team was inserted successfully";
        } else {
            $GLOBALS['message'] = "The team was not inserted";
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "We are sorry. A problem occurred5:" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    
    $conn = null;
}
```

Comment: I would be surprised if the other functions are interfering, once you define a function() variables like $statement that you have defined inside the function are only available in that scope, so other functions are unable to alter the variable.  If you are still getting the same error, there must be another cause

Comment: @bumperbox thanks for that. I'll keep looking then!

Comment: In the `bindValue` calls, remove the leading `:`.  Leave them where they appear within the query, just not at the bind.

Comment: What is `$_POST["TeamName"]`? Is it empty? Is it missing?

Comment: @PaulT. , I tried that but  I still have the same error. I'll leave them out just in case.

Comment: @miken32, TeamName is not empty. It's the column I want to insert new team names into.

Comment: No, "TeamName" is the column. `$_POST["TeamName"]` is a variable, and it's not being set. Check your form code to ensure your form elements are named and being submitted properly.

Comment: @miken32 thank you! That was the issue. I was very confused thinking my table was the issue. Sorry, my question was deleted and I can't give you a vote, but yours was the answer.